# group_by_day and sum works incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a code:

```
total_rate = company.crews
                    .joins(:assignment)
                    .where(assignments: { date: week[:from]..week[:to] })
                    .group_by_day('assignments.date', format: '%Y-%m-%d')
                    .joins(:workers)
                    .sum('workers.rate')
```

in output, we have, as a crew with 2 workers, with rates = 4,5 and it should be 9. It's correct.

If in the last line it’s easy to do .sum ('workers.rate'), then everything is grouped normally, and summed up.
and the output is

> {13:00 => 9} 9 is worker.first.rate = 4, worker.last = 5.

But, here, when I try to multiply by a condition more time, it turns out that every worker.reit is multiplied by the time difference,
But you need the amount of worker rate 9 * 13:00,

```
.sum('workers.rate * (time_arriving - time_leaving)')
```

not 4 * 13.00 + 5 * 13.00

That’s the trouble ...

Comment: There is no `group_by_day` method in Ruby on Rails. What do you expect the method to do? Where is that method define? Did you write it on your own or do you use a gem that provides that method?

Comment: what data type is time_arriving and time_leaving?

Comment: yes, https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Comment: @Pascal t.time "time_leaving"
    t.time "time_arriving"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Postgres:

'time' - 'time' will return an interval, multiplying it with an integer will not change the type.

You will need to extract the hours first, then you can multiply it by the rate.
This query shows you how to do get the hours:

`select extract(epoch from time_leaving - time_starting) / 3600 from assignments`

Note that `select extract(hour from time_leaving - time_starting) from assignments` will only extract full hours, so `12:00 - 10:15` will return '1'